# How to style a table from horizontal layout to vertical layout with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a table, original is like this (for desktop version)

[image: Original]

I am using media queries to change it like this on mobile version and need to make it with pure CSS

[image]

How could you made this?

Here is my Jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/478c6yxg/2/

**UPDATE**

1st try thanks to Andy https://jsfiddle.net/st8kcqyu/

2nd try thanks to Exodus http://jsfiddle.net/478c6yxg/5/

And my html code

```
<div class="view-content">
    <table class="views-table cols-6" border="1" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="views-field views-field-scald-thumbnail">
                </th>
                <th class="views-field views-field-title">
                    Title</th>
                <th class="views-field views-field-field-colour">
                    Colour</th>
                <th class="views-field views-field-field-size">
                    Size</th>
                <th class="views-field views-field-quantity">
                    Quantity</th>
                <th class="views-field views-field-commerce-total">
                    Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="odd views-row-first views-row-last">
                <td class="views-field views-field-scald-thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/84x114" width="84" height="114" alt="">
                </td>
                <td class="views-field views-field-title">
                    Manteau vert M</td>
                <td class="views-field views-field-field-colour">
                    Vert</td>
                <td class="views-field views-field-field-size">
                    34</td>
                <td class="views-field views-field-quantity">
                    1</td>
                <td class="views-field views-field-commerce-total">
                    $120.00</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: can you accept the idea of having 2 tables? One is for desktop one for mobile

Comment: @Andy not for the momment, that will be last option

Comment: Did you try anything?  Anything at all?

Comment: @cimmanon tried this https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by the previous work by [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2426840/andy), I used absolute positioning to place the image more or less where you need it.

However, there is still some work to be done on the bottom border and this will depend somewhat on the dimensions of the image.

A more better solution would need more constraints based on the desired layout.

Responsiveness may be limited.

**Note:** I think the trick is to add the border around the wrapping block and adjust the table/table-cell borders accordingly.  This trick will work best if the image is shorter than the overall height of the table.

```css
thead {
    float:left
}
tbody {
    float:right
}
thead th {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
tbody td {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
thead th:first-child {
    display:none;
}
td:first-child {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-width: 1px 0 1px 1px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
td:first-child img {
    display: block;
}
.views-table {
    margin-left: 90px;
    border: none;
}
.view-content {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;    
}
```

```html
<div class="view-content">
    <table class="views-table cols-6" border="1" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="views-field views-field-scald-thumbnail"></th>
                <th class="views-field views-field-title">Title</th>
                <th class="views-field views-field-field-colour">Colour</th>
                <th class="views-field views-field-field-size">Size</th>
                <th class="views-field views-field-quantity">Quantity</th>
                <th class="views-field views-field-commerce-total">Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="odd views-row-first views-row-last">
                <td class="views-field views-field-scald-thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/84x114" width="84" height="114" alt="">
                </td>
                <td class="views-field views-field-title">Manteau vert M</td>
                <td class="views-field views-field-field-colour">Vert</td>
                <td class="views-field views-field-field-size">34</td>
                <td class="views-field views-field-quantity">1</td>
                <td class="views-field views-field-commerce-total">$120.00</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Just what I needed, now I am fixing some issues from the PSD Design thanks

Answer (score 4):

I have created a poorly conducted solution. I have to hide the img to get the layout right. This probably is not the answer you want. But the goal of this JSfiddle is to inspire others and offer a possible path.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/st8kcqyu/)

CSS:

```
thead
{
    float:left
}
tbody
{
    float:right
}

thead th {
    display: block;   
}
tbody td
{
    display: block;
}

thead th:first-child
{
    display:none;
}

td:first-child
{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: upvote for almost a solution, but the image is very important to show

Comment: Thanks for the upvote but I really cant come up with a way to move one <td> out of the table

Comment: @Andy Your solution is pretty close and with some tweaking, can do the job give or take a bottom border. See my attempt below, inspired by your post.